# Prime numbers between two numbers

Tags: c++

I try write program print prime numbers between two numbers but I have problem when I run it.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void prime(int m, int n) {
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = m; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
        {
            if (i %m == 0)
                p = p + 1;
        }
        if (p = 2)
            cout << m << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int m, n;
    cout << "enter two numbers" << endl;
    cin >> m >> n;
    prime(m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to read how to write a minimal complete verifiable example of your problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Right now, your question does not contain enough information for anyone to understand what is your particular issue and how to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void prime(int m, int n)
{
    for(int i=m; i<n; i++)
    {
        bool isPrimeNumber = false; 
        for (int j=1; j<m; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0&&j!=1) {
                isPrimeNumber = true;
                break;
            } 
        }
        if(!isPrimeNumber)
          cout << i << endl; 
    }
}


int main()
{
    int m, n; 
    cout << "enter two numbers" << endl; 
    cin>>m>>n; 
    prime(m, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Bowen Kuang
when I run to code who wirite it and enter tow number (1,10) then output was print all number from 1 to 10
but I want to print prime numberes for all number between tow number that enter as(2,3,5,7)
please rewrite it

Comment: I want to code as this but it need to editing to become right:    #include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void prime(int x, int y){
for(int i=m; i<n; i++)
{
for (int i=1; i<m; i++)
{
 if(i %m==0)
p=p+1; 
}
if(p=2)
cout <<m <<endl; 
}
}
 int main()
{
int m, n; 
cout <<"enter two numbers"<<endl; 
cin>>m>>n; 
prime(m, n); 
return 0; 
}